# cant access the local database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection, web-hosting

I host ASP.Net (MVC4) web site on Somee.com, but when i try to login to the web site its give an error please help me out to fix this matter thank you.

This is my "connectionStrings"

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="GuestDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the message that i get every time
[image]

My website -http://www.brownhotel.somee.com/

Comment: Please enable debugging and give us more detailed error message. Also check whether the localdb instance is running - use cmd and sqllocaldb info command.

Comment: Does the link to your website is in someway related to your problem? I ask because it could be seen as a subtle form of advertising.

Comment: @rocky Sir I host this site already but i don't know why this occurred what kind of details you want to know ???

Comment: Enable debugging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx Get more info about your localdb instances: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx

Comment: @rocky already done that sir but still i have the issue . .

Comment: And what are the results? :)

Comment: @rocky Thanks, it's problem of sever